# Replacing the last non-nAn value to the last column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My current dataframe is this:

`df.head()`

Output:

| Name | Gender | Country | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Male | America | **1993** |
| Betty | **1968** | NaN | NaN |
| Calvin | NaN | **1995** | NaN |
| Debra | Female | **2000** | NaN |

I would like to shift all the last non-NaN values to the last column of the dataframe.

- Every row will have the year in the last non-NaN column of the dataframe
- What every row definitely has is the 'Name' and 'Year' value
- The 'Year' value could be either in Gender or Country column

So basically I need a code that populates this output:

Output:

| Name | Gender | Country | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Male | America | **1993** |
| Betty | NaN | NaN | **1968** |
| Calvin | NaN | NaN | **1995** |
| Debra | Female | NaN | **2000** |

Thank you for your help

Comment: How'd your data get like this in the first place? It may be possible to fix the source of this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ffill` on index axis because `Year` is your last column and the last valid value of a row is a year.

```
df['Year'] = df.ffill(axis=1)['Year'].astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
     Name  Gender  Country  Year
0    Adam    Male  America  1993
1   Betty    1968      NaN  1968
2  Calvin     NaN     1995  1995
3   Debra  Female     2000  2000
```

To be safe, you can use `pd.to_numeric` to remove values where year is not defined for a row:

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_numeric(df.ffill(axis=1)['Year'], errors='coerce')
print(df)

# Output
     Name  Gender  Country    Year
0    Adam    Male  America  1993.0
1   Betty    1968      NaN  1968.0
2  Calvin     NaN     1995  1995.0
3   Debra  Female     2000  2000.0
```